# Paypal Mass pay IPN with payment_status as Denied

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, masspay

So as per this documentation IPN for mass pay 
https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/#id091EB070DUI

we can get the payment_status = denied if that is case do we still  get information about individual items or we do not get any information about individual item.

If we get information about the individual item what is the value of status_x

and if the transaction is denied is there any transaction fess applied.

I have requirement that if the mass pay is denied I need to mark the individual item as denied.If the payment_status is completed or processed I use the unique_id_x value to map to entries in my database or want do so in case f denied

Also the documentation mentions reason_code is set only if status = Failed

there is not explicit variable named status ;there is status_x or payment_status which one of it is ?

if the it is status_x : then should it not be reason_code_x for each item individually
if it is payment_status : but we do not have payment_status as Failed.

Answer (score 0):

By "individual item" do you mean one of the transactions in a batch of Mass Payments? You would get an IPN post for each transaction. If three of ten fail you would get ten IPN posts. Seven for the completed payments and three for the failed.

The `status_x`value would be `Failed` or `Blocked` depending on the reason the transaction failed.

A `payment_status` of `Denied` means that the Mass Payment process didn't start at all. Like the example mentions, probably because of insufficient funds in the senders account. If you want to track the status of the specific payments watch for the `status_x` value.

Edit: You can test IPN in the Sandbox. It's enabled on US Seller accounts by default.